# Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Action) when the project is already evaluated

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-7.0

Project type: Android

Gradle wrapper: gradle-7.5

Gradle plugin: 7.4.2

app module build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt"
}

android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }

    flavorDimensions "app", "channel"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "app"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }

        product {
            dimension "app"
        }

        google {
            dimension "channel"
        }

        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            def dirPath = project.projectDir.absolutePath + '/build/outputs/apk/' + dirName + '/'
            def filePath = ''
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "xxx.apk"
                filePath = outputFileName
            }

            variant.getAssembleProvider().get().doLast {
                if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
                    def cmd = 'cd .. && ./ossutilmac64 cp -f ' + dirPath + filePath + ' oss://android-test-sz/' + filePath
                    exec {
                        ExecSpec execSpec ->
                            executable 'zsh'
                            args '-c', cmd
                            standardOutput = out
                    }
                    println(out.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

when I run shell “./gradlew assembleDevGoogleRelease” to build apk and upload apk to oss with Gradle 7, unfortunately, the build fails. (Gradle 6.x is ok)

```
> Task :app:assembleDevGoogleRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '...app/build.gradle' line: 222

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:assembleDevGoogleRelease'.
> Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Action) when the project is already evaluated.
```

The error line 222 is the “exec {” in doLast.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance. :slight_smile:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the applicationVariants.all on the outside block

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'
}

android {
    // ...

    defaultConfig {
        // ...
    }

    flavorDimensions 'app', 'channel'
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension 'app'
            applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
        }

        product {
            dimension 'app'
        }

        google {
            dimension 'channel'
        }
    }
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def dirPath = project.projectDir.absolutePath + '/build/outputs/apk/' + dirName + '/'
    def filePath = ''
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "xxx.apk"
        filePath = outputFileName
    }

    variant.getAssembleProvider().get().doLast {
        if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
            def cmd = 'cd .. && ./ossutilmac64 cp -f ' + dirPath + filePath + ' oss://android-test-sz/' + filePath
            exec {
                executable 'zsh'
                args '-c', cmd
                standardOutput = out
            }
            println(out.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try your solution but got the same error message

Comment: If you place it on the outside of android block as well?

Comment: Thanks a lot, place the block of "android.applicationVariants.all{}" outside of android block work well.

Comment: Can you explain why it works, I really don't understand the "exec{}" can not run in the "doLast" block. (The original code works with Gradle 6.x)

Comment: I thinks its a matter of how the file is read & executed. Unfortunately I cant explain why it is